# Как получить отрендеренное изображение image Control-а WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В `xaml` создаю изображение и задаю ему нужную высоту:

```
<Image x:Name="CatView" Height="38" Source="_мое_изображение">
```

Как в коде получить изображение, которое получится после пересчета размеров?

Т.e., где лежит мое изображение с размером равным `CatView.RenderSize`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну сама картинка может быть нигде и не хранится, или хранится в недоступном месте. Но можно легко получить снимок *любого* контрола в картинку. Например, так:

```
// получаем изображение
var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)control.ActualWidth, (int)control.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rtb.Render(control);
// сохраняем в PNG
var png = new PngBitmapEncoder() { Frames = { BitmapFrame.Create(rtb) } };
using (var file = File.Create(path))
    png.Save(file);
```

Документация: [How to: Encode a Visual to an Image File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-a-visual-to-an-image-file).

Comment: Ваш код не дает мне мое изображение в уменьшенном виде. Я получаю пустое изображение размером 1кб

Comment: @kovdryavlad: А вы окно с картинкой показываете?

Comment: да, картинка всегда есть на форме. А форма одна

Comment: @kovdryavlad: Странно, у меня работает. А вы не вызываете этот код, например, в конструкторе?